# How to send elements of array as separate lines in email message in asp.net with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, email

I have an application where I will need to send an email in html format to 
individuals who place an order.
The order items are placed in a database, and are to be retrieved
and then sent to the client who placed the order in this format:

The format of the email should be in this format:

```
   The items you ordered are:
        Dishwasher
        Laptop
        Ironing Board
        Xbox 360
```

I am stuck on how to get this format. Seeing my array already exists, i believe it should be
something like

```
            for (int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
             {
         messagebody+="<br/>"+array[i]
              }  
        client.Send(msg);
```

Am i on the right track?

Comment: Depending on your email format, you should be fine with what you are doing for HTML, or substitute `\n` for `<br>` for plain text. Haven't you tried your method?

Comment: Yes you are on the right track

Comment: foreach might be a bit cleaner, `foreach(var item in array) messagebody+=string.format("<br/>{0}", item);` or even more simply `messagebody += string.Join("<br/>", array);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could avoid the whole for/foreach loop using the string.Join method:

```
string[] arr = { "one", "two", "three" };
string messageBody = string.Join("<br/>", arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

To be able to include HTML elements in mail body, you should use

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
 message.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

Another option without using HTML, include `\n` in your message like:

```
messagebody+="\n "+array[i]
```

Comment: That is another option.

Comment: I would personally prefer `Environment.NewLine` over the hardcoded `\n` there.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct your code should work as written, though it might help to add a newline after each append as noted in comments

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of your array, you might want to consider using the StringBuilder class. Please find a sample below:

```
StringBuilder messageBodyBuilder = new StringBuilder();

foreach (String singleEntry in array)
{
    messageBodyBuilder.AppendFormat("{0}<br />", singleEntry);
}

messagebody += messageBodyBuilder.ToString();
```

This will work if the message body is HTML. If the email body is plain text, just replace "`<br />`" with "\n".